# ADC Preliminary Design

Tags: sensor, analog, adc, digital-logic

I am designing a circuit, to use an ADC(mcp3008) to read voltage, current, and temperature sensors. I have a few questons about this, as I have never done this before.

1. I am going to use single ended mode; Can I just plug in the sensor directly to the ADC, or does it need to go through some processing or filtering?
2. I need to read voltages that vary from 90-108v the maximum voltage that my board can supply the ADC for Vref is 12 Volts. How can I read this high voltage?
3. Are there any additional considerations that I should keep in mind to make my circuit as reliable as possible?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Depends on the sensor output impedance, frequency content, and signal range. If the output impedance is high, you need a buffer. If the frequency content is too high for the ADC, you need a low pass filter. If the signal range is too small, you need amplification.
2. Use a voltage divider to bring it down to the range in question, then buffer with an op-amp if necessary.
3. Read about the ADC's input capacitance characteristics. I've written [a blog entry that will help explain this](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/110.php). If you're repeating your samples slowly, it's not a big deal, but rapid sampling makes this important. The sampling time before ADC conversion is also important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this really clears things up!

Comment: Necro comment here, but I found the article super straight-forward and useful.